# add duration in timestamp data do not give right time moment js

Tags: momentjs

I want to create an array of 10 minutes span for 1 hour using moment.js but it fails on first step.

```
var startTime = moment().unix();
var endTime = moment().add(1,'h').unix();  
getTimeSheet(startTime,endTime);
var getTimeSheet = function(st, et) {
       console.log(arguments);
       var timeSheet = [];
       var duration = moment.duration({'minutes' : 10});
       var ct = st;
       console.log(ct);
       while (ct <= et ){
            var n10 = moment.unix(st).add(duration).unix();
            timeSheet.push(n10);
            console.log(n10);
            ct = n10;
      }
      console.log(timeSheet); 
};
```

But this is Unable to create array

Comment: if you really need to use unix timestamps then you need to use `moment.unix(st)` to transform they to moment.js objects (or `moment(st * 1000)` ;) )

Comment: that really helps. Thanks. how do we create array . i m using `while(st<=et) ` but loops goes so long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each iteration of `while` loop you are adding 10 minutes to `st` variable. So `n10` and `ct` still contain the same value. That's why this loop never ends.

You need to change:

```
var n10 = moment.unix(st).add(duration).unix();
```

to

```
var n10 = moment.unix(ct).add(duration).unix();
```

You can also check working example with some minor improvements here:
https://jsfiddle.net/65gL9tgr/2/